# How to open a shell while/after running a Docker container without overriding existing CMD?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So the last line in my Dockerfile is:

```
CMD Django-admin startproject testproject
```

I'm new to Docker and I just learned that I can only use the CMD line once in a Dockerfile and that running /bin/shell in the following example overrides the CMD:

```
docker run -it <containerid> /bin/bash
```

My question is how do I open a shell without overriding the Django-admin startproject CMD?  I have looked into docker attach but this does not seem to open a shell.  I feel like I am missing something obvious here.  I just want to run my container and go into the shell and poke around and ensure my Django project is actually being created.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply run container without overwriting command in background:

```
docker run -d --name container_name <image_name>
```

And next you can attach to running container with new session:

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
```

Comment: I am running into a problem here,  If I run the 'docker run' command you posted, docker ps shows no containers running.  However, if I do a docker run with /bin/bash then docker ps shows the container running.  So the problem is I cannot attach to the container because it is not running (with your solution)

Comment: @david, you need to check CMD and `docker logs` then, it is nor running, because the CMD is finished (program exit, or has errors so was not able to start, and so on)

Comment: I have removed the CMD from the Dockerfile all together so the issue is no longer related to CMD.  If I run the docker run command posted by Slawomir, there are no containers running.  If I do a docker run with -it, the container is running and there are no errors.

Comment: I will make a new post for this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457681/why-wont-my-docker-container-run-unless-i-use-i-t